# Scrapy middleware to replace single request with multiple requests

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I want a middleware that will take a single Request and transform it into a generator of two different requests. As far as I can tell, the downloader middleware `process_request()` method can only return a single Request, not a generator of them. Is there a nice way to split an arbitrary request into multiple requests?

It seems that spider middleware `process_start_requests` actually happens *after* the `start_requests` Requests are sent through the downloader. For example, if I set `start_urls = ['https://localhost/']` and

```
def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
   yield Request('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

it will fail with `ConnectionRefusedError`, having tried and failed the `localhost` request.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Defining `process_start_requests` in a spider middleware, yielding `scrapy.Request('http://www.stackoverflow.com')` works for me

Comment: @paultrmbrth You're right; that was not the source of my problem. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026532/async-query-database-for-keys-to-use-in-multiple-requests) explains my predicament better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what would be the logic behind transforming a request (before being sent) into multiple requests, but you can still generate several requests (or even items) from a middleware, with this:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    for a in range(10):
        spider.crawler.engine.crawl(
            Request(url='myurl', callback=callback_method), 
            spider)
```

Comment: Will these still go through subsequent downloader middlewares?

Comment: Not completely sure, but yeah I think it should.

Comment: Is there a way to do this sending out Deferred instead of Request? Looks like the scheduler middlewares won't accept Deferred arguments.

Comment: @eLRuLL can you help me? : https://stackoverflow.com/q/73389010/8519380

Comment: @Sardar looks like you got the help needed :+1: